# Solr Computed Index field in Sitecore SXA Search Result rendering variant

Tags: sxa, solr

Is there any way to render computed index field of solr using Search Result rendering variant in Sitecore SXA 1.9?

Comment: is this what you want - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13578/computed-index-field-as-a-rendering-variant ?